# Preserve UITabBar when pushing a ViewController from a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitoolbar

I'm trying to push a View Controller from a TableView displayed inside a UiViewController that is included in a UITabBarController (it's more simple that it looks...)

The View Controller is pushed BUT the UITabBar is hidden by this view controller, and I'd like to keep this UITabBar displayed.

I tried a lot of things, unsuccessfully.
Here is my code:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let v = UIViewController()
    v.view=UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,200))
    v.view.backgroundColor=UIColor.redColor()

    v.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
    self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
    self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(v, animated: true)
}
```

Any hint will be really appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: How did you set up the transition between two view controllers? From storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: programmatically, the code is included in my post

Comment: problem solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37708012/tab-bar-hidden-by-view-controller-when-pushed-inside-my-uitabbarcontroller