# Tab bar hidden by view controller when pushed inside my UITabBarController

Tags: ios

Note: And I tried to set the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed to false everywhere it was possible...

Here is how I initialize my UITabBarController in my AppDelegate file:

```
func initTabBarController()
{
    let myVC1 = MapVC()
    let myVC2 = MapVC()
    let myVC3 = MapVC()
    let myVC4 = MapVC()

    let controllers = [myVC1,myVC2,myVC3,myVC4]

    self.myTabBarController = UITabBarController()
    self.myTabBarController.viewControllers = controllers

    myVC1.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(
        title: "Map",
        image: image1,
        selectedImage: image11)
    myVC2.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(
        title: "Map",
        image: image2,
        selectedImage: image21)
    myVC3.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(
        title: "Map",
        image: image3,
        selectedImage: image31)
    myVC4.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(
        title: "Menu",
        image: image4,
        selectedImage: image41)

    self.tabNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self.myTabBarController)

    self.tabNavigationController.navigationBar.translucent = false
}
```

Now Here is how I set the rootViewController of my main window:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.initTabBarController()
        appDelegate.window!.rootViewController =    
appDelegate.tabNavigationController
        appDelegate.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

And here is finally how I try to push a new view controller inside one of my ViewController (MapVC):

```
    let v = UIViewController()
    v.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

    self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(v, animated: true)
```

When this code is executed, the Yellow view is well displayed, but the bottom tab bar is hidden.

And I'd like to still have my Tab Bar!!!

I tried to set the property hidesBottomBarWhenPushed to false to any object I can, unsuccessfully.

Please help me!!!

Regards,
Alx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have embedded your tabBarController in a NavigationController. That is probably why the tabs are hidden when a new ViewController is pushed on the stack. Instead embed each of the tabBarController's ViewControllers inside their own NavigationController.

Comment: thanks a lot! I did that and it's working ike a charm now, thanks a lot!